# How to pass a class from child to parent without export in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to pass the classes from child to parent (sveltekit).

```
In child
========================
<script>
</script>

<ul class="one">
   <li class="two"></li>
   <li class="three"></li>
</ul>
```

Without exporting the class or having: global(), can I use the class in the parent? I am trying to do this so that I can use the child component and style it differently in parents (where it is inherited)

Edit:

I can use :global here. But I am using 'SASS' in the parent and I am trying to access the style of both **one** **two** and **three**.

I am thinking if I could use one global statement on the outerstyle **(one)** and nest the two and three inside in SASS like the following

```
In the parent
=====================
<style lang="scss">
  :global(.one) {
      background-color: orange;
         .two {
              font-size: 2rem;
          }
          .three {
              font-size: 1rem;
          }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should not use `:global` at the top level unless you style e.g. the `html` element at the top level. It would change *all instances* of the child component, as soon as this component is loaded in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without exporting the class or having: global(), can I use the class in the parent?

No.

Either use a property to distinguish variants (and change the style in the child internally based on that) or use `:global()` but scoped to some element in the parent. E.g.

```html
<div class="content"><Child /></div>
<style>
  .content :global(.one) {
    ...
  }
</style>
```

For nesting with a preprocessor, you can also use `:global` like this:

```html
<style lang="scss">
    .content :global {
        .one {
            background: orange;
            .two { font-size: 2rem; }
            .three { font-size: 1rem; }
        }
    }
</style>
```

You can also use custom CSS properties to change styling from the outside.

Comment: Thank you. The CSS preprocessor method works well in my case. Can you provide an example of how to use the custom CSS property (second method)

Comment: There is nothing Svelte specific about custom properties except [this special syntax](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives---style-props) for creating a wrapper for components and setting properties on that. Please see other questions or e.g. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) on the subject.